# Is there a way to comment selected lines instead of the selected range of text in Visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

If I try to comment out several lines in Visual Studio I typically get this result:

```
int f/*oo = 1;
float bar = doSo*/mething(foo);
```

But what I want to happen is:

```
//  int foo = 1;
//  float bar = doSomething(foo);
```

Every other IDE/text editor that I'm used to produces the second result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Visual Studio [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=munyabe.ToggleComment) does the trick